# Integrating Mozila Pdf.js with Meteor

Tags: javascript, pdf, meteor, mozilla, meteorite

I want pdf.js only on client side in meteor. It's been so long i am working on this. So this post will little long to give you better understanding what i have done so far.

I started with using meteor package [pascoual:pdfjs](https://atmospherejs.com/pascoual/pdfjs). After following example given in this package i got only one page inside `<canvas>` like **Hello World** [example](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld) in pdf.js. But i want like [demo](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) given by pdf.js. After some research and post in stack**overflow** got no conclusion that how to do same with this package.

One more package recommended by pdf.js is [peerlibrary:pdf.js](https://atmospherejs.com/peerlibrary/pdf.js). I haven't use it bcoz it is for both client and server side. I want to only client side to view the pdf file providing the url.

Then I started How can i setup PDF.js manually in my project. I followed [Setup PDF.js in a website](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-PDF.js-in-a-website). Downloaded the [gh-pages](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/gh-pages/) branch from pdf.js as told to do in instruction. Copied [**build**](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/gh-pages/build) and [**web**](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/gh-pages/web) directory and put in my meteor project. I customized files as per meteor, project structure looks like:

```
.meteor/
client/
  |- build/
  |    |- pdf.js
  |    |- pdf.worker.js
  |- cmaps/                                            -- contains all .bcmap files
  |- stylesheets/
  |    |- viewer.css
  |- web/
  |    |- compatibility.js
  |    |- debugger.js
  |    |- l10n.js
  |    |- viewer.html
  |    |- viewer.js
lib/
  |- locale/
public/
  |- compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf                -- default pdf
  |- /* all images present in image directory*/
```

**Errors after run the project:**

1. client/web/viewer.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you).

   - remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` form **viewer.html**
2. client/web/viewer.html:23: bad formatting in HTML template

   - remove `<html>` and `<head>` from **viewer.html**. Kept only body.

Hurray!!! Now black viewer is coming. But default pdf is not loading... :(

After a long time i found something in **build\pdf.js**

[image]

I changed here (no idea it will effect in future or not):

```
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
```

Once Again, Hurrey! default pdf file is loading properly & toolbar also working fine.

**Viewer.html** contains `<body>` tag. So, it is loading in brower at very first landing. If i remove `<body>` if it giving `bad formatting in HTML template`, because then we have to make it as a template.

Now my Questions are:

- How can i route to **viewer.html** if it is not a template?
- If i make make **viewer.html** as a template then how can i keep the **viewer.js** code?
- Last but not the least, am i going to right direction? Is there any other way...?

Please share your helpful thoughts. Waiting for a healthy discussion...

Answer (score 1):

> - How can i route to viewer.html if it is not a template?

You will need to use a template, that's how meteor routes works

> - If i make make viewer.html as a template then how can i keep the    viewer.js code?

You will need to wrap it into your template `rendered` function:

```
Template.YourTemplate.rendered = function() {
    //do your stuff
};
```

> - Last but not the least, am i going to right direction? Is there any    other way...?

There is no obvious way to achieve what you want and there is several other ways, as you identified yourself. I guess the right approach is (at first at least) the one that works. Give a try to the template approach and have a look at [how to use iron-router](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial).

However, if you have an hard time achieving the pdf display your way, I advise you to give a try to peerlibrary:pdf.js. The fact that it works also on server shouldn't be a show stopper, it won't make a significant difference in performance and it could end up being useful for implementing features you don't think about yet.

Answer (score 1):

use iframe to load the url like this

```
<iframe src="pathof/web/viewer.html?file=url of pdf file"></iframe>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use google docs viewer within an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url={{url}}&embedded=true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

at url write your url which you want to open pdf .